# ionic : how to put a value to key in angular using push

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

im looking to push data to array uisng push but i want to put a favorite boolean value in the key
the key is **isFav**

```
 this.datagp.forEach(getData =>             
    this.datapush.push({
      logo : getData.logo,
      name : getData.name,
      isFav :  this.favoriteProviderService.isFavoriteitem(getData.name)
      .then( (value) => {   value? true : false} ) 
                       })
                    )
```

in console isFav get  **ZoneAwarePromise**

in html page  {{isFav}} showing **[object Promise]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try something like this - let me know if this solves your problem.

```
 this.datagp.forEach(getData =>   
  this.favoriteProviderService.isFavoriteitem(getTitle.name).then((value) => {           
     this.datapush.push({
       logo : getData.tvg.logo,
       name : getData.name,
       isFav :  value ? true : false
    });
  });
 );
```